# PhpStorm doesn't open files via xdebug.file_link_format

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm doesn't open files via xdebug.file_link_format.

I tried different formats, and still doesn't work. I open link in new tab and nothing happens. Path is writing correct in address bar

```
xdebug.file_link_format = "phpstorm://open?file=%f&line=%l"
```

Comment: It was working. Maybe because my disk name is BOOTCAMP (C:\\). Or phpstorm not in PATH? Or PhpStorm removed this feature?

Comment: Can I create my custom protocol for phpstorm, what can open file and line?

Comment: It's only supported for macOS out-of-the-box, for Windows, you need a 3rd party solution: https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879

Answer (score 1):

I created my own protocol and custom program to open file in phpstorm

myproto.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto]
@="phpstorm"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myproto\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe\" \"C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\web\\ahk\\phpstorm.js\" \"%1\""
```

phpstorm.js:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs')

let path = process.argv[2]
path = path.replace('myproto://','')
path = decodeURIComponent(path)
path = path.replace(/\/$/,'')

ls = child_process.exec('"C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PhpStorm 2019.1.1\\bin\\phpstorm64.exe" ' + path + '')
```

php.ini:

```
xdebug.file_link_format = "myproto://%f:%l"
```